# Inverse of sum of inverse matrices

Tags: inverse

My method needs to solve the following problem.
$$A = (B^{-1} + C^{-1} - D^{-1})^{-1}$$

Is there any way to rewrite this to avoid "too much" matrix inverse when implementing this in python?
The matrices are all symmetric and positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply both sides of the equation by $(B^{-1}+C^{-1}-D^{-1})$ and get $$(B^{-1}+C^{-1}-D^{-1})A = I$$ thus getting rid of the "inverse of sum" part.

But I don't think you can avoid calculating the inverses of $B,C$ and $D$.